# How should I deal with zero values in a list of values to be summed/averaged?

Tags: summation, average

I work in a warehouse where we take components and put them together to make a finished good product.

We have these values for each component:

1. Quantity Required
2. Quantity Used
3. Variance (Quantity Used- Quantity Required)
4. Overage ((Variance/Quantity Required)) * 100%

So basically these values tell me how much we needed, how much we used, and how much we wasted.

At the bottom of the report that shows all these values, I take the sum of Quantity Required, Quantity Used, and Variance. I also take the average of Quantity Required and Quantity Used and subtract these averages to find the average Variance.

**The problem:** Sometimes the Quantity Required value for a component is zero. How should I adjust my summations/averages accordingly?

**What I've tried:** I've simply made the summations/averages **ignore** the rows where the Quantity Required is zero, but I think this is **wrong**. If my boss asks me "What is the average overage for Item X for this year?" my method will ignore the rows with zeros in the Quantity Required column, thus ignoring an amount in Quantity Used that is technically still an amount to consider.

**Sample Data of 1 item being used across multiple jobs:**

```
                   Quantity Required    Quantity Used           Variance       Overage

Job A              1000                 1100                    100            10%
Job B              900                  800                    -100           -11.1%
Job C              0                    300                     300            (N/A)

    Summations:    1900                 1900                    0              0%
    Averages:      950                  950                     0              0%
```

Comment: Why $0$ is a special case at all? It seems more intuitive to me when changing value from $0$ to $1$ doesn't lead to "jumps" in the statistics.

Comment: Do you have data on the cost of the components?

Comment: @Justthisguy yes, there is a cost structure to all of the components in our facility, which is why I'm concerned about ignoring 300 units used (from **Sample Data**).

Comment: @Abstraction well.....some components have a significant cost at a Quantity Required of $1$. For example, for a particular job we use only 5 units of an item but each one costs $ \$600 $.

Comment: I mean that I don't see a reason for difference between $0$ and $1$ being much more important than the difference between $1$ and $2$. Also, if quantities in different rows have significantly different meanings, the meaning of their sum is unclear (for example, reducing cheap components by $5$ and adding $5$ costly components will have no effect on the sum while changing the actual situation significantly).

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely not ignore the zero rows.

The simplest thing to do would be just to sum the Quantity Required and the Quantity Used , then average by dividing by the number of rows in the report.

You can sum the Variance the same way. Summing the Overage makes no sense - mark it N/A.

You should not average the Variance and the Overage by using the row values Compute those directly from the Summations of the two columns.

Comment: So then let's say there is only $1$ row: it has a $0$ for the Quantity Required and $300$ for the Quantity Used. The sum of Quantity Required would be $0$ and the sum of Quantity Used would be $300$. The Variance would be $300$ and the Overage cannot be calculated due to a divide by zero error. This is a result of ignoring the zero rows. Are you sure? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat For a 0 in Quantity Required, whether in a single row or as a total, report (N/A) as in your example for the Overage.

Comment: So then picture this: my boss asks me to generate the report of an item's usage for 4 years. If I tell him the value of the total overage/average overage is "N/A", he might get upset (even if it's correct to say that). This is a tricky situation. I guess in that case an estimated value is fine, which would mean that I would just ignore the zero rows. Would you agree?

Comment: I disagree. Ignoring zero rows can mislead your boss. Suppose the Quantity Required in all but one of the rows was 0. If you reported just the values from the single nonzero row he would think that value applied pretty much all the time on average, when in fact it was for just one of many Jobs. I think the true best solution is to talk to your boss, so that you know how he plans to use these data, and work out together what he wants to see. Don't try to guess what he has in mind.

Comment: Just talked to him. I decided to show him both the regular totals/averages (not ignoring any rows) and also the weighted totals/averages (ignoring the zero rows) and also talked about the difference between both. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

It's a good rule of thumb to never add quantities that have different units. When you add, for example, the entries in the first column, the first entry has units "number of component A", whereas the second entry has units "number of component B". So what are the units of the sum?

A good way to aggregate this data is to compute the total cost of the goods used and the total cost of goods used under normal usage (i.e. if the quantities used in the "quantity required" column were used). Then you overage cost is

(cost of goods used) - (cost of goods that should have been used),

and your overage percentage is

((cost of goods used) - (cost of goods that should have been used)) / (cost of goods that should have been used).

You can do this analysis item-by-item as well.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. I'm not adding different units. I've clarified my sample data - there is only 1 item being used across multiple jobs, so the unit of the item stays the same. For example, this component could be raw candy measured in kilograms. So each job will register their respective amount of candy used in kilograms.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers to this question, it depends on what the 0 value represents.

If a sample is missing, then there is no way to impute its values, so the zero sample can be excluded from mean and average calculations.

However, if you have a situation where you started with 10 items and used 8 of them, then a remainder of 0 indicates an error of some sort. In such a case, the mean and average is meaningless. You first need to account for the reason(s) for the discrepancy. Then you will likely have a different data set on which to compute the mean and average.